# Assembly - Mouse click second try not working

Tags: debugging, assembly, click, mouse, interrupt

I need to make a program that generates a random number and prints a white block in a random position based on the number, I have the number, I have the white block, but then the user needs to press the block with left mouse click. When starting the program the first block can be properly pressed but after that the program immediately exits. I ran the program in turbo debugger and I can see that while the program reads the interrupt to get mouse position and status, it just goes through those lines and continues.

```
mouseCheck:
xor bx, bx

; Check x, y of mouse alongside it's status
mov ax, 3h              
int 33h

; Check left mouse click
cmp bx, 01h     

; If left mouse wasn't clicked on, do another mouse click check
jne mouseCheck          

; Adjust CX to range 0-319, to fit screen
shr cx, 1 

; Move one pixel, so the pixel will not be hidden by mouse
sub dx, 1   

; Read pixel info
mov ah, 0Dh             
int 10h

; Check if Pixel is white
cmp al, 15      

; If yes go print another square
je secondaryPrintSquare
```

Comment: Clearly, that's not all of the relevant code since we can't see the code referenced by secondaryPrintSquare

Comment: hint 1: you should check if just bit 0 is set, after 33/3, not if the whole status byte is 1 (`and bx,1` will mask it out)
hint 2: if bx is 1, then BH ('page number' for 10/0dh) will be 1. are you sure you want that?

Comment: IIRC (too lazy to check the docs, that's your responsibility), the `int 33h` returns current status of buttons, not clicks. So you will need to put there some delay, or wait for "off" state to catch release of button, before waiting for second click. Also with HW switches on buttons you may with certain devices receive "bounced" signal, having few short "on" blips after the user hits the button hard, so you may need eventually some kind of "debounce" logic to clear the signal from button.

Comment: I solved my issue, I needed to not only check for mouse click but also for mouse release. About the minimal amount of code, you are absolutely correct. My first time posting a question in these forums so I wasn't sure how much to include. I will be sure to improve my questions in the future. Thanks to those who answered.